# How to disallow user from changing permissions on a device owner app?

Tags: android

Note : The application by default cannot be uninstalled as it is a device owner app with device admin privileges and all permissions are granted by default. But it is possible for the user to disable these permissions. Is there anyway to disallow the user from doing this by greying out the permission change toggle button? I have seen this being disabled in Samsung KNOX based EMM apps.

Comment: Well, maybe a system app can change it own permissions back?

Comment: Yes that is exactly what I want to disable. And as I said I have seen it being done in other apps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This solved it for me :

targetSdkVersion should be 23 or above for this to work.

```
DevicePolicyManager dpm = (DevicePolicyManager) getSystemService(Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE);

ComponentName mDeviceAdmin = new ComponentName(this, AdminReceiver.class);

    try {
                String[] permissions = context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(context.getPackageName(),PackageManager.GET_PERMISSIONS).requestedPermissions;
                for (String permission : permissions) {
                    boolean success = dpm.setPermissionGrantState(mDeviceAdmin,
                            getPackageName(), permission, PERMISSION_GRANT_STATE_GRANTED);
                    if (!success) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Failed to auto grant permission to self: " + permission);
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

PERMISSION_GRANT_STATE_GRANTED : The permission is granted to the app and the user cannot manage the permission through the UI.

PERMISSION_GRANT_STATE_DENIED : The permission is denied to the app and the user cannot manage the permission through the UI.

PERMISSION_GRANT_STATE_DEFAULT : The user can manage the permission through the UI.